# Nested GET request Nodejs Expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, get

i have a problem with my code.
I want to create a nested GET request using Nodejs and Expressjs, i use GET reuqest like:

```
http://localhost/zigbee/zi?name='Hello'
http://localhost/zigbee/zs?name='Hello'
```

It is possible to create a main route `/zigbee/`e and 2 subroute `/zi/ /zs/` ?

I think an implementation like:

```
app.get('/zigbee/',function(req,res){ ...
     app.get('/zi',function(req,res){ ...
     app.get('/zs',function(req,res){ ...
   }}}
```

It is possible to do? thanks all

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
app.get('/zigbee/:routeParam',function(req,res){
    var param = req.params.routeParam;
    //do stuff
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to route the request like below

```
app.route('/zigbee/:action').get(function (req, res) {
  if (req.param('action') == 'zi') {
    // your logic
  }
  if (req.param('action') == 'zs') {
    // your logic
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a router and load it in the main app, as shown below.

```
var zigbee = express.Router()
zigbee.get('/zi', function ...)
zigbee.get('/zs', function ...)

app.use('/zigbee', zigbee)
```